# C++ Hazelcast with Protobuf serialization: String is not UTF-8 formatted

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, hazelcast

I want to be able to send serialized Protobuf data using HazelCast. I understand why it gives me the error but is there a way around it?

Here is the sample code I am using:

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <hazelcast/client/HazelcastClient.h>
#include "testProto.pb.h"

using namespace std;

int main(){

    // create object
    tutorial::Input protoInput;
    protoInput.set_innum(500);

    // buffer to store serialized string
    string stringBuffer;
    protoInputer.SerializeToString(&stringBuffer);
    
 
    // set up hazelcast client
    hazelcast::client::ClientConfig(config);
    hazelcast::client::HazelcastClient hz(config);
    hazelcast::client::IMap<string,string> map = hz.getMap<string,string>("myMap");
    
    //error is from trying to write it
    map.put("Input", stringBuffer);

    return 0;
}
```

testProto.proto

```
syntax = "proto3";
package tutorial;

message Input{
    int64 inNum = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From protobuf [doc](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/cpptutorial#parsing-and-serialization):

> SerializeToString(string* output) const;
>
> serializes the message and stores the bytes in the given string. Note that the bytes are binary, not text; we only use the string class as a convenient container.

So it's not safe to store them as string in IMap, as it is prone to fail in case of non UTF-8 formatted. I suggest you to store protobuf as vector of bytes - where `hazelcast::byte` is `unsigned char`:

```
hz.getMap<string, vector<hazelcast::byte>>("proto_map");
```

Comment: This solution works but since protobuf serializes as an array, I would have to keep copying arrays to vectors and vise versa for deserializing. I wonder if there is a cleaner approach...possibly through Hazelcast's custom serialization

Comment: I'm not sure about how to store that binary directly. You can avoid copying via using a wrapper class that implements one of the Hazelcast serialization methods. In write/read methods of de/serialization, you can de/serialize the protobuf fields manually (via writeInt, readInt, etc.) . Alternatively, you can use writeByte/readByte for each byte of the de/serialized, binary protobuf string.